# org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder does not define or inherit

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

When I try to execute the selenium test getting an error

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod com.testingvasitum.testcases.BaseTest.setUp
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.io.File findDefaultExecutable()' of abstract class org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.
```

I tried to execute the selenium test and I was expecting to launch the chrome browser successfully

Comment: include code for driver initialization...  (the "new ChromeDriver()" bit...)  Some sort of type issue here...